# How to use background-image css property with Django static files

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

*I know similar questions have been answered but there are no clear answers for how to do this in a linked css file, all suggest doing directly in the html file itself* I have a `Jobs` project, with the following structure to get to the images folder:

Jobs/core/static/core/images/search.jpg

How can I set an `input` element's `background-image` property to 'search.jpg' in a css file that is referenced with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/css/index.css' %}" />`
 ? I have seen similar questions asked and all of the answers suggest things such as setting it inline on the element itself, but how can this be done in a linked css file?

Answer (score 1):

**Django cant see or write CSS files**, all your CSS that needs Django static import you should put it inline (i like to create a new html files with my inline css with static urls and than include it on my template)

```
<div style="background-image: url({% static 'core/images/search.jpg' %});" />
```

Or you can use relative paths in your css files, but this will probabily give you a headache when start to setup in production

```
.someClass {
   background-image: url(/static/core/images/search.jpg);
}
```